# Server doesn't accept double quotes in the query

Tags: post, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to make the same request as [here](https://v4.subgraph.polygon.oceanprotocol.com/subgraphs/name/oceanprotocol/ocean-subgraph/graphql?query=%7B%0ApoolSnapshots(where%3A%7Bpool%3A%220x800d0c1e4fb219a2d9bd2f292aa91abdcd862915%22%7D)%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20baseTokenLiquidity%0A%20%20%20%20datatokenLiquidity%0A%20%20%20%20spotPrice%0A%7D%0A%7D) using requests and python. This is my code:

```
address = "0x800d0c1e4fb219a2d9bd2f292aa91abdcd862915"
data= """{"query":"{poolSnapshots(where:{pool:"%s"}, orderBy: date){id baseTokenLiquidity datatokenLiquidity spotPrice}}","variables":null,"operationName":null}"""%(address)
response = requests.post('https://v4.subgraph.polygon.oceanprotocol.com/subgraphs/name/oceanprotocol/ocean-subgraph', data=data).json()
```

But when I execute the code I got the following error:

```
GraphQL server error (client error): expected ,or} at line 1 column 39: 0
```

What am I missing? I'm texting the double quotes wrongly? Thanks for answers!

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try to send URI encoded value of that string that contains quotes. See [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) function.

Comment: It still returns the error. Trying to parse only the address quotes, it says: `unexpected character '%'`\nExpected `IntValue`, `FloatValue`, `StringValue`, `BlockString`, `true`, `false`, `null` or `Name`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API expects a stringified JSON that you wrapped into the triple quotes. The right way is to use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to stringify the query payload (`dict`). It will convert the payload data types to corresponding JSON types.

```py
import requests
import json

address = "0x800d0c1e4fb219a2d9bd2f292aa91abdcd862915"
url = 'https://v4.subgraph.polygon.oceanprotocol.com/subgraphs/name/oceanprotocol/ocean-subgraph'

data = {
    "query": "{poolSnapshots(where:{pool:\"%s\"}, orderBy: date){id baseTokenLiquidity datatokenLiquidity spotPrice}}" % address,
    "operationName": None,
    "variables": None,
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
print(response.json())
```

Comment: absolutely correct. Thank you!